# Docker container to surf via I2P network

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm looking for a docker container for surfing the internet anonymously via I2P network inside the Linux container.

It should be easy to use and connect to I2P network on startup.

I could use [`ZedCode/docker-i2p`](https://github.com/ZedCode/docker-i2p) (I2P dockerized), but it requires configuration of the local browser. What I require is to use commands inside the container such as `curl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I2P comes with a [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/i2p/i2p.i2p/blob/master/Dockerfile). The quickest way to use it is to run:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh meeh/i2p.i2p
```

Then inside container, run:

```
/entrypoint.sh &
export http_proxy=http://localhost:4444/
export https_proxy=http://localhost:4445/
```

To test the configuration, run:

```
wget -O- http://example.com/
wget -qO- ifconfig.me
wget -qO- ifconfig.co/json
```

To configure different proxies, see: [Docs](https://geti2p.net/en/docs) and [Ports used by I2P](https://geti2p.net/en/docs/ports).

---

To run I2P node within Docker, just run:

```
docker run meeh/i2p.i2p
```

then it needs to be accessed through the [exposed ports](https://github.com/i2p/i2p.i2p/blob/master/Dockerfile#L59) (e.g. from the browser or another container).

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, done this one, but not 150+ others. I'm waiting for this [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319770/191655).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder who deleted my comment.